# Euler's totient function of $n^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Prove that $\varphi(n^2)=n\cdot\varphi(n)$ for $n\in \Bbb{N}$, where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function.

Comment: Formula $\mapsto$ LHS = RHS

Comment: this rule is valid if and only if n is the product of two primes, not for an ordinary n. then, we will be able to use the multiplicative feature of totient function to expand its products. finally, we need to use the prime power feature of totient function to prove this. cannot prove this here because this question is not accepting answers.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**: Use that for any $\;n=p_1^{a_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_k^{a_k}\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;p_i\;$ primes, $\;a_i\in\Bbb N\;$ , we have

$$\varphi(n)=n\prod_{i=1}^k\left(1-\frac1{p_i}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$Hint:$ Use multiplicity of Euler's function and fundamental theorem of arithmetics.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Using this identity

> $$\varphi(n^m)=n^{m-1}\varphi(n)$$